# Python-MySQL prepared statement error while selecting where a value IS NULL

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement, isnull, isnullorempty

I want to select rows where a value is null but I get this error on executing using Python-MySQL prepared statement.

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

```
import mysql.connector

connection = mysql.connector.connect(database="XXXXX", user="XXXXX", password="XXXXX", host="XXXXX")
cursor  = connection.cursor(prepared=True)
parameters = ["Ahmed", None]
statement = "SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name_first = ? AND start_date IS ?"
cursor.execute(statement, tuple(parameters))
```

Comment: Why are you using parameters to supply null? I would guess that that is where the problem is but don't know python so won't commit to that. However, whatever language is in use in this case you gain nothing by using a parameter instead of writing '...IS NULL' directly into the SQL statement and using no parameters.

Comment: I just simplified the query to make sure the issue IS NULL but I  use prepared statement with a lot of parameters and I have no problem with them, Just the issue appears when using NULL as a parameter, I will edit the post to contain another parameter.